# django: is it safe to store the users fixtures along with the project sources?

Tags: django

Is it safe to store the users fixtures along with the project sources? And therefore to commit them or to upload them on the server to install them?

I know the passwords are encrypted but if someone gets them, wouldn't it be easier to crack them then?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords, certificates, keys, secrets and so on in the repo. And why you are using fixtures to store user information? It should be in database.

Comment: I am using the django fixtures to load them in the database the first time.

Comment: How would you manage the users for different environment (production vs staging for example)? Using fixtures does not seem to be the best solution.

Comment: For staging i'm using fixtures with basic data and some users, but passwords are different. Production server means that you will not destroy and recreate your data, so i don't need fixtures here. If you want some basic superusers, install them manually.

Comment: Yes I see your point. I was just making sure that the fixtures were loaded only once. I use Ansible to deploy my application and the first time I load the fixtures, I create a file to flag it so that the next time I run my ansible playbook, the fixtures are not loaded.